# Titanium Studio - Alloy | Font size of a label

Tags: android, xml, titanium, titanium-alloy

I am trying to get going with Titanium Platform using Alloy but It's not quite as easy as it looks. I'm currently running an alloy project with following code. Very basic nothing weird but on the first screen which is auto generated I cannot read the text on the device. It's like 4px in height.

```
<Alloy>
<Window class="container">
    <Label id="label" onClick="doClick">Hello World!</Label>
</Window>
</Alloy>
```

I have tried different options to get the font size bigger but no result.
I can create apps in Eclipse but Titanium doesn't seem so well documented. I would be pleased if anyone could refer me to a good website to learn or just solve this problem. That would be a start.

I also found this:

```
"Label": {
width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
color: "#000"
}
```

So I'm guessing I need to change the var Ti.UI.SIZE?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this

```
"Label": {
  font:{
    fontSize: '18dp'
  },
  width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
  height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
  color: "#000"
}
```

and for reference use their docs

http://alloylove.com/#

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/